# Is there an event timestamp available in the firestore `onDelete` function?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

If I'm using a firestore function triggered on firestore database events such as `onUpdate()` or `onCreate()`, for most writes I can check the `change.after.updateTime` field to see when the write occurred, which will be different than `Timestamp.now()`, the time the function is invoked.

However, when the document is deleted, triggering `onWrite()` or `onDelete()`, `change.after.exists` is `false` and `change.after.updateTime` is `undefined`. Is there any way to get access to the time that the database event occurred, rather than the time that the function is invoked?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no information about when the exact transition occurs available for such a delete operation. You'd have to pass or get something out of band (i.e. writing it into a separate document, or somehow reading it from the logs), but I can imagine how that'd get pretty hairy quickly.

I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) for this with the team.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate that you took the time to give an answer even if it's not possible currently